# Can I use Stack Exchange to tell people about my new tool or technology

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I have created some useful tools and I am willing to put all those tools on a website and let people use those tools and donate me money if they like it. These tools are related to web design and project management etc. But I don't have a budget for advertisement.

Now if I ask a dummy question on Stack Overflow (which I know only my tool can solve or my tool would be the choice) then will this be spam advertisement? Because this way I will reach the exact audience that I need and it will help them? I have not done this yet btw.

Please guide me as i am struggling with this scenario, and also tell me if there is anything wrong with the question and i will update it or change the tags etc. dont downvote. Thank you.

Comment: GitHub seems to be exactly what you need https://github.com/ I doubt a question on SO would be well recived, unless you got it just perfect.

Comment: We can only answer questions about Stack Exchange here, not general questions about advertising your tools, so I've edited your question to limit it to SE related advertising.

Comment: i am not asking about my tool only i havent even mentioned what my tool does or the name of my tool. I am just asking about how to reach like minded and profession people easily without investing in advertisement.

Comment: this question can legitimately help others as there are so many people with such awesome products, but they dont have enough money for advertisement .

Comment: That's fine but this site is the meta site for Stack Exchange, not a site about advertising. All questions here must specifically relate to Stack Exchange or they are closed as off topic.

Comment: “this be spam advertisement?” - Yes, it would be considered spam and promptly removed and reported.  “... dont downvote.“ - I don’t agree with your plan, and I am issuing a downvote, to encourage you NOT to spam us with your advertisement.

Comment: I didn't read it all - I saw "don't downvote", downvoted and ignored the rest.

Answer (score 10):

See [How not to be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) in the help.  (The topic exists on every site; I've linked to the help here on Meta.SE.)

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> Here are some specific behaviors to avoid - even with the best of intentions, these will nearly always result in your posts being flagged as spam: [...]
>
> - Don't include links except to support what you've written. Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself, and links should always be directly relevant to a part of your answer.

This help topic is about answers and doesn't even raise the topic of self-answered questions.  Self-answered questions are permitted but often held to a higher standard.  A self-answered question to *promote your product* is likely to do badly.

If one of your tools happens to be the basis of a useful answer to somebody else's question, go ahead and answer that question and explain how your tool can help.  Be sure to disclose your affiliation.  But please don't create questions just so you can answer them to promote your tools.  That's not how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: this is pretty straight forward, i will surely read the topic u shared. Although i have one question, just curious, why this question was downvoted , its not that this post is a spam or something ....

Comment: @MamoonAhmed I guess some people think see your goal as self-promotion and want to discourage that.  (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: Thank you for not downvoting. Someone even changed the heading of the question. lol . Anyways my previous 5 years was not successful at understanding the stackoverflow community :P no offence to u btw ...

Answer (score 5):

> tell people about my new tool or technology

You've defined "advertising" there, and that's not allowed on any Stack Exchange site.

> But I don't have a budget for advertisement.

And here you've kinda admitted your goal *is* advertising.

What would your *question* be? It'd be a forced question around the solution your tool provides to be able to provide an answer and promote your tool. This isn't in the spirit of how the sites work really.

> Now if I ask a dummy question on Stack Overflow (which I know only my
>   tool can solve or my tool would be the choice) then will this be spam
>   advertisement?

I'm not 100% sure on the official stance, but in my personal opinion you should be careful, I doubt most communities will like it much if it's obvious or known.

Creating good quality Questions to self answer is welcomed as it builds a library of good content that helps others. But actively creating Q&As intentionally to promote your site is likely to be frowned upon. The sites would degrade so rapidly if everyone started doing that.

You don't really have a question to ask, you have a product to sell and you would be creating a false question just to link to your site.

> Because this way I will reach the exact audience that I need and it
>   will help them?

We all have websites which we could argue helps someone, that doesn't negate any potential definition of "self promotion" or "spam-like".

Comment: "If the *only* reason you're here is to sell something or drive traffic to your site, then please avoid posting answers." (help center, emphasis original) Not sure why spam seeds aren't explicitly mentioned but I assume it's too obvious by analogy....